# WebAPI 2 does not serialize primitive return types

Tags: c#, json, serialization, asp.net-web-api

I've got a WebAPI that returns primitive types, like int, Int64, UInt64 etcetera.

```
public Int64 Count()
{
    return 1337;
}

Returns:

1337
```

Even though my client requests data with the HTML header

```
Accept: application/json
```

The API still just returns the number, so invalid in JSON terms. In XML it will correctly serialize as

```
<long>1337</long>
```

Is there any "easy" way to solve this for a lot of methods?

**Tried solutions**

I tried to use this simple approach:

```
public Dictionary<string, Int64> Count()
{
    return new Dictionary<string, Int64>() {{"Count", 1337}};
}
```

This has a very ugly XML output though. So now I made a MODEL for a primitive type..

```
public Number Count()
{
    return new Number(1337);
}

Returns:

{ "Value" : 1337 }
```

I'm looking for something easier, I might end up writing a generic class which does nothing else then wrapping primitives.

Comment: "The API still just returns the number in JSON": what do you mean? What exactly does it return, and what do you expect?

Comment: You say that the data is returned as JSON when the http header is set to `Accept: application/json`, this is exactly what it should do, what are you expecting to happen?

Comment: It returns simply the number, this is not valid JSON. My client JSON deserializer fails on this.

Comment: Well, what would you expect the JSON representation of a number to be? JSON.NET has no problem deserializing the string "1337" into the int value 1337. I don't know if it's valid JSON, but it's the only representation that makes sense IMO...

Comment: As far as I'm aware, `1337` is not valid JSON, but @ThomasLevesque has a point: what _do_ you expect the representation to be? An int is not a key/value-pair. If you don't want to return a model just for an int, how about returning a `dynamic`? `return new { long = 1337 };`